# Missing sound: final skt letters

Tags: pronunciation, phonology, phonetics, silent-letters

I've noticed that many Americans in movies usually omit letter k when it falls between s and t sounds at the end of any word like in asked, tasked,

Can we generalize that as a rule, so the word masked will be /mast/ and risked will be /rist/?

The same thing with final mpt, can we omit /p/ in cramped, empty, attempt?

Comment: We don't omit the /k/; we just don't pronounce it quite the same way as a regular /k/. It's called an *unreleased* /k/. We can tell the difference between *wrist* and *risked*, although it's a considerably smaller difference than between (say) *sin* and *skin*. See [this Wikipedia entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/No_audible_release).

Comment: For your other question, for me there actually is no difference between the final consonants in *dreamt* and *attempt*. But it's more like I'm adding an unreleased /p/ to *dreamt* than dropping the /p/ from *attempt*. They both end with the same sound as in *rasped*. (But since in English, final /mt/ = final /mpt/, if you drop the /p/ from *attempt*, nobody will misunderstand you.)

Comment: Some American dialects (including African-American)  switch the consonants around so that *asked* becomes *aksed*.

Comment: @PeterShor I don't know about Gen Am, but /k/-elision is often [a feature of those words](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=QjKcBQAAQBAJ&pg=PA127&lpg=PA127&dq=Practical+Phonetics+and+Phonology+/k/+elision+asked&source=bl&ots=OnpCqAZNxm&sig=PUfdVdVRVd3tMsG4puBKpJVcM08&hl=en&sa=X&ei=AeufVb2hJqKWygPM_6fQBA&ved=0CC0Q6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q=Practical%20Phonetics%20and%20Phonology%20%2Fk%2F%20elision%20asked&f=false) in standard British English.

Comment: @PeterShor There's no such thing as an unreleased /k/. That usually result in death :D Though of course they can be masked or have no "audible release".

Answer (score 3):

In some dialects in Britain (particularly around the Thames Estuary) you will hear for example *asked* pronounced without the 'k'.

**Example**

*'I never said as 'ow 'e shouldn't; I only **arst** yer if it was the sime.' 'Yea, thet's 'oo I mean.' ''Is nime is Blakeston—Jim Blakeston. I've only spoke to 'im once.*
**Liza of Lambeth: By Somerset Maugham**

Note: In the above, the 'r' is **not** pronounced - it is used to indicate the lengthening of the 'a' sound. Estuary English is non-rhotic.

Most people however do pronounce all the components of such words. You may miss them because in 'asked' only the vowel sound is voiced. All the consonants are unvoiced.

Comment: RP speakers hardly ever pronounce the /k/ in *asked*.

Comment: @Araucaria: speak for yourself. As chasly said, it is not voiced, but it is certainly there.

Comment: @TimLymington This ain't a matter of opinion, it's been empirically measured. So they've gone out and tested thousands of speakers. Unless you've got some similar evidence contradicting this, I'll stick with the current thinking based on evidence :)

Comment: @Araucaria Do you have a link to this research? You can't take the high ground on evidence if you don't produce it.

Comment: @mikeagg [See here](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=QjKcBQAAQBAJ&pg=PA127&lpg=PA127&dq=Practical+Phonetics+and+Phonology+/k/+elision+asked&source=bl&ots=OnpCqAZNxm&sig=PUfdVdVRVd3tMsG4puBKpJVcM08&hl=en&sa=X&ei=AeufVb2hJqKWygPM_6fQBA&ved=0CC0Q6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q=Practical%20Phonetics%20and%20Phonology%20%2Fk%2F%20elision%20asked&f=false).

Comment: @Araucaria-Nothereanymore. - I say the k in asked, and I'm as RP as they come.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey I can't really comment on that. I can say that most speakers would say that they pronounce all of the underlying sounds in most words. I've even had trainee teachers swear that they say both 't's in *mustn't*. In short, very many speakers would say they always pronounce the /k/ in *asked*, and may even say it to themselves as an isolated word in an unnatural and overly careful way. However, when you give them a dialogue to act out, the /k/ mysteriously vanishes. You might be one of the vanishingly small group of speakers who usually pronounces /k/ is *asked. I couldn't comment.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey So introspection doesn't seem to be a good way of checking here. One way to check (not fool-proof) is to record yourself saying something like *they asked the masked gunmen* twelve times as fast as you can and see if you can hear twenty-four [k]s in there.

Comment: @Araucaria - Not here any more - Of course, you should also record saying it without the 'k' and see if you (or someone else) can distinguish between them.

Comment: @Araucaria - Not here any more.  Your experiment proves nothing. If the subject knows what they were saying, they may simply assume that they can hear the "k". There is a *lot* of known work in psychology about this effect - we largely hear what we expect to hear.  By having a control, we can test ourselves more reliably. It doesn't have to be contrived. For example, a non-rhotic Brit could simply alternate between reading  "they asked" and "they arsed" or a longer sentence spoken quickly.

Comment: @chasly-supportsMonica It’s always a bit difficult trying to use contrived pronunciations, but in principle, were this not already a well-established empirical fact, something along those lines might make an interesting informal experiment. Speakers can definitely hear the difference once primed, but in everyday life no one notices whether there’s a [k] there.

Comment: @chasly-supportsMonica It's a very simple contrast that virtually all speakers can hear, so long as there's an actual [k] in one of the examples. This isn't an abstract theoretical point. People play with this stuff every day in undergrad phonetics classes across the country. It's bread and butter stuff.

Answer (score 2):

Some of the answers and comments here seem to say that the /k/ in *asked* is not elided in standard Englishes. To counter this misconception, as well as to through some light on *masked* and *risked*, I thought it might be a good idea to put some information here from vetted published sources, and world-renowned professional phoneticians of English.

The following goes for Standard Southern British English (also called *RP*). It's taken from *Practical Phonetics and Phonology* by Beverley Collins and Inger Mees, Routeledge, 2008:

> The sequence /skt/ has elision of /k/ instead of, or if preceding consonants, in addition to /t/:
>
> - *masked gunmen* /mɑ:st gʌnmən/ or /mɑ:s gʌnmən/, *they asked us* /ðeɪ ɑ:st əs/
>
> [*Practical Phonetics and Phonology* p. 127]

It would seem then that one should be able to extrapolate from this to words like *tasked* and possibly *risked*.

However, the following is from Professor John Wells' [blog here](http://www.phon.ucl.ac.uk/home/wells/blog0609.htm). It's the entry for Thur 7 September 2006 (in case you want to check out the rest of the entry):

> As an ordinary vocabulary item *asked*, the past tense of *ask*, is frequently pronounced without the [k]. In its LPD entry I write it as "ɑːs*k*t", showing by the italicization that the velar plosive can be omitted. If it has no [k], it is homophonous with *arsed*, which explains our eggcorn.
>
> Although we are very ready to elide the [k] in *asked*, we are not so ready to do so in other *-sk* past tenses: *masked, basked, tasked, whisked, tusked*. Nor can we readily elide the [p] in *clasped, rasped, lisped, cusped*. (OK, in rapid speech I concede that they all might go.)

I leave it to the gentle readers here to make of that what they will!

Answer (score 1):

No. Some people may not always pronounce these words clearly, some people do. If you want to come up with a rule for others to follow (good luck with that!), how about "pronounce words clearly so they are not confused with other words".

For the record, I have never heard *masked* pronounced as *mast*, though the difference can be subtle and those for whom English is not their first language may perhaps miss it.

Comment: That's not what *rule* means in this context.